# Creating a spreadsheet for MTG cards that automatically updates prices based on a specific website

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

excel novice here; good with formulas for basic office work but no experience with macros.

I have a list of approx 1100 items in an inventory with prices that fluctuate almost daily. I am trying to apply a macro to fetch the prices from a website (face-to-face games) and apply a 10% reduction when the document is opened. I have read a few how-to articles but the explanations quickly went over my head.

Comment: Please read [ask], you didn't ask a question. Note that a list of requirements is not asking a question. Also this website is no free code writing service, therefore you need to precise your *"question"* which is a way too broad. It is even unclear what kind of answer you expect us to give. We need to know what you have tried and where exactly you got stuck. There are a lot of examples here on Stack Overflow how to scrape data from websites. If the website provides an API definitely use that instead of scraping. Also see [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: You're right. Thank you for being decent about how to use the site, and still providing help in the mean time. I'll make sure to make myself aware of the guidelines in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with PEH, If the websites have API, its way easier to get data from them. Here's my extremely lacking function that I use for very simple API calls:

```
Public Function API( _
                ByVal URL As String, _
                ByVal Action As String, _
                Optional Body As String = "") As String
    
    'Action is GET, POST, PUT or DELETE
    
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    http.Open Action, URL, False
    If Action <> "GET" Then http.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    
    If Body <> "" Then
        http.Send Body
    Else
        http.Send
    End If
    
    If http.Status = 200 And Action <> "GET" Then
        API = "Successfully Sent!"
    Else
        If http.Status <> 200 And http.responsetext = "" Then
            API = http.statustext
        Else
            API = http.responsetext
        End If
    End If
    
End Function
```

This is just a very basic function to plug in a URL and send a block of text or ask for that URL to send you its text. What you would do is find out the URL scheme for the website you're trying to get data from and send a series of these API calls with Action="GET" at those URLs. Then you just have to parse the text they send back to you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can probably take this and reach my solution. Much appreciated

Comment: If you liked my answer, please click that green check mark under the voting arrows.